# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMBus'

Tags: python, linux, windows, import, i2c

Good evening,

I have been working on SMBus communication to my hard drive and have been able to read values through a program called readwriteeverything. Now, I want to create my own program to read and write registers in python that imports smbus. So, I decided to base my code off of this example:

```
from smbus import SMBus

bus = SMBus(1)    # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

DEVICE_ADDRESS = 0x15      #7 bit address (will be left shifted to add the read write bit)
DEVICE_REG_MODE1 = 0x00
bus.write_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS, DEVICE_REG_MODE1)
bus.read_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS)
```

However, when I try to run the single line of code:

```
from smbus import SMBus
```

I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SMBus
```

I've tried python2, python3, installing numerous packages, such as python3-smbus, and even tried to build the package and install that (although that was based on a Raspberry Pi guide and this is with a desktop.)

I've tried on both windows and linux and have run into the same issue.

How can I get this command to work properly?

Comment: Have you tried installing it through pip?

Comment: yes, I have tried by following this guide: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbus-cffi, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SMBus module. Try:

> pip install smbus-cffi --upgrade

Look here for details of the package [smbus-cffi 0.5.1 details](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbus-cffi)

Comment: That didn't work, here is the output when I run that command: `pip install smbus-cffi --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: smbus-cffi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smbus_cffi-0.5.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: cffi>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi-1.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from smbus-cffi)
Requirement already up-to-date: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg (from cffi>=1.1.0->smbus-cffi)
Cleaning up...` it appears everything was already up to date.

Comment: Are you familiar with a virtualenv install?  Create a virtual environment with 'virtualenv mytest'. Then run 'source ./mytest/bin/activate'.  At that point you are in a clean virtual environment and can rerun the pip command. Fingers crossed that may address whatever is blocking your main python command.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, this did not seem to do the trick. I tried it in pypy, as well as directly through the terminal after building it in the virtual environment. I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 if it matters at this point.